# What kind of fish are these?

Tags: species-identification

This should be pretty easy. We have a tropical fish tank, and among a few other species we have an adult pair of these guys. The female is a live-bearer, and seems to be giving birth to two young at a time. However, I can't for the life of me remember what kind of fish they are.

[image: fish]

The male is in the foreground, and the female in the background. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is a Red Wag Platy (*Xiphophorus maculatus*)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [Red Wag Platy](http://www.liveaquaria.com/product/prod_display.cfm?c=830%201103%202728&pcatid=2728) (*Xiphophorus maculatus*). Apparently it is a common tropical aquarium fish. Wikipedia does not show a picture of this variant. However a google image search with this will return the images of fish that you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, you are correct. I accepted the other answer because yours was posted 10 seconds too late - I doubt you'll mind, though :)

Comment: @MattDMo No prob. I realized that after a few minutes and I thought I'll delete mine but someone upvoted. So I thought I'll let it stay :P